# Python: Append tuple to a set with tuples

Tags: python, set

Following is my code which is a set of tuples:

```
data = {('A',20160129,36.44),('A',20160201,37.37),('A',20160104,41.06)};
print(data);
```

Output: `set([('A', 20160129, 36.44), ('A', 20160104, 41.06), ('A', 20160201, 37.37)])`

How do I append another tuple `('A', 20160000, 22)` to `data`?

Expected output: `set([('A', 20160129, 36.44), ('A', 20160104, 41.06), ('A', 20160201, 37.37), ('A', 20160000, 22)])`

Note: I found a lot of resources to append data to a set but unfortunately none of them have the input data in the above format. I tried `append`, `|` & `set` functions as well.

Comment: data.add(('A', 20160000, 22))?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the trick is to send it inside brackets so it doesn't get exploded

```
data.update([('A', 20160000, 22)])
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why passing in a list of tuple(s) works?

Answer (score 9):

just use `data.add`. Here's an example:

```
x = {(1, '1a'), (2, '2a'), (3, '3a')}

x.add((4, '4a'))

print(x)
```

Output: `{(3, '3a'), (1, '1a'), (2, '2a'), (4, '4a')}`

Answer (score 1):

```
s = {('a',1)}
s.add(('b',2))
```

> output: {('a', 1),('b', 2)}

```
s.update(('c',3))
```

> output: {('a', 1), 3, 'c', ('b', 2)}

There can be loss of generality by using **update**.
Better to use **add**.
It is a cleaner way of operating sets.

Answer (score 0):

This failure also matching the question title:

```
your_set = set
your_set.add(('A', 20160000, 22))
```

because it should be:

```
your_set = set()
```